# Way to use my computer to reboot iOS device

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

jailbroken I am looking for some private API or piece of code which will allow me to reboot iOS device.Without physically touching the power button.

This is for an app which will be loaded into iPads in a physical enclosure so the power button is inaccessible. The device itself will be in single app mode.

If the device is non jailbroken,is there any API to reboot?
I find some iOS device management softwares can reboot the device when it is connected to computer.But I don't know how to make it.Please tell me,if anyone know.

And if it is a jailbroken device,how to reboot the device?

Comment: wildly off topic IMO

Comment: I want to make a wall of iPad.So I am looking for a way to control the device reboot together without touching the power button.

Comment: With jailbreak you can execute `reboot`. Without jailbreak - I don't think there is a private API for that. But you can do it over USB from your PC - https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/ Diagnostics relay service can do it

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the private framework **SpringBoardServices**

and then simply call SBReboot

```
SBReboot(0);
```